# FindNext Method of Range class failed (C#, Excel)

Tags: c#, excel

I am searching an excel column with the following items:

MT1325
MT0604
MU3509
MT0605
MT0606
MU3509
MT0607
MT0608

And I want the following code to output each item that begins with an MT in a message box:

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        //New Excel App
        Excel._Application oApp = new Excel.Application();
        oApp.Visible = true;

        //Opens Workbook with MT/MU's to be counted
        Excel.Workbook oWorkbook = oApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Users\\sfrey\\Desktop\\Test22");
        Excel.Worksheet oWorksheet = oWorkbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];

        Excel.Range currentFind = null;
        Excel.Range firstFind = null;


        object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

        Excel.Range xlRange = oWorksheet.get_Range("A1");


        currentFind = xlRange.EntireColumn.Find("MT",
        misValue, Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart,
        Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByColumns, Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext,
        true, misValue, misValue);

        while (currentFind != null) 
        {
            // Keep track of the first range you find.  
            if (firstFind == null)
            {
                firstFind = currentFind;
            }

            // If you didn't move to a new range, you are done. 
            else if (currentFind.get_Address(Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1)
                  == firstFind.get_Address(Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1))
            {
                break;
            }


            string cellText = currentFind.Value.ToString();
            MessageBox.Show(cellText);

            currentFind = xlRange.FindNext(currentFind); 

        }

    }
```

The last line of code gives me an error (FindNext Method of Range class failed)..I have been using this for reference (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/e4x1k99a.aspx) and don't understand what could be going wrong.

Thanks

Comment: well the link example has this 3rd to the last param set to false you have yours set to true in this line `currentFind = xlRange.EntireColumn.Find("MT",
        misValue, Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart,
        Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByColumns, Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext,
        true, misValue, misValue);`

Comment: That's not it, I believe that true/false is whether to match case or not.  I did try it though, and it didn't work.

Comment: their example has the following `Excel.Range Fruits = Application.get_Range("A1", "B3");` but you're trying to find it based on the workbook also you have entire column where the example doesn't `xlRange.EntireColumn.Find`

Comment: why don't you try to get it to work using the example from the link first then extend it from there if you need to do more..

Comment: Try making sure you use the same range for both the `Find` and the `FindNext` (i.e. define `xlRange` to include the `EntireColumn` part).

Answer (score 3):

This was fairly frustrating for me, but simply changing:

```
Excel.Range foundCell = nameColumnToSearch.Find(nameToFind);
Excel.Range firstResult = foundCell;

while (foundCell != null)
{
    // Snip: Do some stuff

    foundCell = nameColumnToSearch.FindNext(foundCell);

    if (foundCell.Address == firstResult.Address)
        foundCell = null;
}
```

to:

```
Excel.Range foundCell = nameColumnToSearch.Find(nameToFind);
Excel.Range firstResult = foundCell;

while (foundCell != null)
{
    // Snip: Do some stuff

    Excel.Range foundTemp = foundCell;
    foundCell = nameColumnToSearch.Find(foundTemp);

    if (foundCell.Address == firstResult.Address)
        foundCell = null;
}
```

I do not know WHY... but there it is.  I hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I faced the same problem. In my case I was running a Find inside another Find statement and I fixed following the same way that Matthew Esler has done.

Instead using FindNext, change to Find and set the After: parameter to currentFind. It worked for me. I'm still don't know why FindNext has this behavior.

```
private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    //New Excel App
    Excel._Application oApp = new Excel.Application();
    oApp.Visible = true;

    //Opens Workbook with MT/MU's to be counted
    Excel.Workbook oWorkbook = oApp.Workbooks.Open("C:\\Users\\sfrey\\Desktop\\Test22");
    Excel.Worksheet oWorksheet = oWorkbook.Worksheets["Sheet1"];

    Excel.Range currentFind = null;
    Excel.Range firstFind = null;


    object misValue = System.Reflection.Missing.Value;

    Excel.Range xlRange = oWorksheet.get_Range("A1");


    currentFind = xlRange.EntireColumn.Find("MT", misValue, Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart, Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByColumns, Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext, true, misValue, misValue);

    while (currentFind != null) 
    {
        // Keep track of the first range you find.  
        if (firstFind == null)
        {
            firstFind = currentFind;
        }

        // If you didn't move to a new range, you are done. 
        else if (currentFind.get_Address(Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1) == firstFind.get_Address(Excel.XlReferenceStyle.xlA1))
        {
            break;
        }


        string cellText = currentFind.Value.ToString();
        MessageBox.Show(cellText);

        // currentFind = xlRange.FindNext(currentFind); 
        currentFind = xlRange.EntireColumn.Find("MT", currentFind, Excel.XlFindLookIn.xlValues, Excel.XlLookAt.xlPart, Excel.XlSearchOrder.xlByColumns, Excel.XlSearchDirection.xlNext, true, misValue, misValue);

    }

}
```

See this link too: https://www.pcreview.co.uk/threads/why-is-my-findnext-not-working.4026685/